# Dynamic memory allocation and taking input

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to take user input and store it on the dynamically allocated array. But it looks like I am far away from getting the thing.
What mistake actually I am doing?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct abc
{
    int x;
    int *y;
};

int main()
{
    abc d;
    d.y = new int[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        //cin>>d.y->x; //Error//user_input
        cout<<"Address : "<<(d.y+i)<<endl;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to input the array(`abc.y`) like as follows

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   cin >> d.y[i]; // like this
};
```

Also, do not forget to free the memory afterwards, otherwise memory leak.

---

However, I would recommend using [`std::vector<int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or a [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) instead of raw pointer there.

Also mind that, in case of copying the `abc` to another, you need to implement the own copy-move and required other constructors(aka [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

Answer (score 1):

I assume your error is in the commented line? If so, then what you probably want is `cin >> d.y[i];` rather than `cin >> d.y->x;` (which should not even compile). The `->` operator is used with classes and struct, to take the `x` member in the object pointed by `y`. That's not what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error in your case is that you're not inserting the elements in to each ith element of the allocated array.
Make sure you delete the array after using it as well. I have reshuffled things a bit so that you see the address and values after inserting the elements in to the array.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct abc
{
    int x;
    int *y;
};

int main()
{
    abc d;
    d.y = new int[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cin >> *(d.y+i); // same as cin >> d.y[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout<<"Address : " <<(d.y+i)<< ", value: " << *(d.y+i) << endl;
    }
    delete [] d.y;
}
```